# Java Jung incompatible type casting

Tags: java, casting, jung, vertex

I am trying to iterate through a set of vertices. The vertices are a custom class that I created. Here is my attempt to iterate through the vertices:

```
bCentral2 = new BetweennessCentrality<MyVertex, MyEdge>(g2);

for(MyVertex v : g2.getVertices())
{
    v.setCentrality(bCentral2.getVertexScore(v));
}
```

The error I get is from the line: `MyVertex v : g2.getVertices()` and the message is:

```
incompatible types
  required: graphvisualization.MyVertex
  found:    java.lang.Object
```

So, I tried casting to an `ArraryList<MyVertex>` and I got this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

1. How can I iterate through my set of vertices?
2. The ultimate goal is to set the centrality of each vertex

The following is my code for the MyVertex Class:

```
public class MyVertex 
{
    int vID;                    //id for this vertex
    double centrality;          //centrality measure for this vertex

    public MyVertex(int id)
    {
        this.vID = id;
        this.centrality=0;
    }

    public double getCentrality()
    {
        return this.centrality;
    }

    public void setCentrality(double centrality)
    {
        this.centrality = centrality;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "v"+vID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show how you instantiate `g2`? It looks like you're not using generics correctly and `getVertices()` is returning a `Collection<Object>` which is why the `for` loop won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing `g2.getVertices()` returns a collection. so you can convert your `Collection` to `ArrayList` as:

```
ArrayList<MyVertex> ll = new ArrayList<>(g2.getVertices())
```

Here is the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29)

Comment: That won't work. The reason his `for` loop is failing in the first place is because it's a `Collection<Object>` as noted by the 'incompatible types' error he's receiving.